# Multiple For each loop value to Json string

Tags: php, json, array

```
 $data= array();
 foreach($itfdatas as $key=>$itfdata){

$checkemps = explode(',',$itfdata['employee_id']);


  $data[] = array(
            'id'=>mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['P_id']),
            'job_id'=>mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['quote_id']),
            'job_title'=>mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['job_title']));



foreach ($checkemps as $checkempss){
  $empusers =  $users->ShowAllEmployeeByJobId($checkempss['profile_id']);



      $data[] =array(
            'helper_id'=>mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['profile_id']),
            'helper_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['name']));




   }

$msg=array('status'=>'success','emp_job_list'=>$data);
$itfresinfo=json_encode($msg);

     }

    echo $itfresinfo;
```

The above code gives the below output

```
          {
          "status": "success",
        "emp_job_list": [
        {
        "id": "1",
        "job_id": "MM\/IR1",
        "job_title": "2 Men with 4.5 Tonne Truck"
        },
        {
        "helper_id": "1",
        "helper_name": "Vivek"   
        },
        {
        "helper_id": "3",
        "helper_name": "Akhilesh"
        },
        {
        "id": "2",
        "job_id": "MM\/IR2",
        "job_title": "This is the test asasascvcvcv"
        },
        {
        "helper_id": "1",
        "helper_name": "Vivek"
        },
        {
        "helper_id": "3",
        "helper_name": "Akhilesh"
        }
        ]
        }
```

But I want the below output

```
                         {
            "status": "success",   
            "emp_job_list": [ 
            {  
            "id": "1",
            "job_id": "MM\/IR1",
            "job_title": "2 Men with 4.5 Tonne Truck",
            "helper_detail":[  
            {  
            "helper_id": "1",
            "helper_name": "Vivek"  
            }
            ]

            },
            {  
            "id": "1",
            "job_id": "MM\/IR1",
            "job_title": "2 Men with 4.5 Tonne Truck",
            "helper_detail":[  
            {  
            "helper_id": "1",
            "helper_name": "Vivek"  
            }
            ]

            }
            ] 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. But watch out for typos. I haven't tested it.

If this does not work, add to the question a sample of how `$itfdatas` looks like and one of what `$users->ShowAllEmployeeByJobId($checkempss['profile_id'])` returns.

```
$data= array();
foreach($itfdatas as $key=>$itfdata) {
    $employee = array(
        'id' => mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['P_id']),
        'job_id' => mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['quote_id']),
        'job_title' => mysql_real_escape_string($itfdata['job_title'])
        'helper_detail' => array();
    );
    $checkemps = explode(',',$itfdata['employee_id']);
    foreach ($checkemps as $checkempss) {
        $empusers =  $users->ShowAllEmployeeByJobId($checkempss['profile_id']);
        $employee['helper_detail'][] = array(
            'helper_id' => mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['profile_id']),
            'helper_name' => mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['name'])
        );
    }
    $data[] = $employee;
}
$msg = array('status' => 'success','emp_job_list' => $data);
$itfresinfo = json_encode($msg);
echo $itfresinfo;
```

Comment: $itfdatas looks like below

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [job_id] => MM/IR1
            [job_title] => 2 Men with 4.5 Tonne Truck
           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [job_id] => MM/IR2
            [job_title] => 3 Men with 4.5 Tonne Truck
        )

)

Comment: Thanks for you quick Answer

Comment: what I have to do for one more child of $employee['helper_detail'][]

Comment: something like this  foreach ($checkemps as $checkempss) {
        $empusers =  $users->ShowAllEmployeeByJobId($checkempss['profile_id']);
        $employee['helper_detail'][] = array(
            'helper_id' => mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['profile_id']),
            'helper_name' => mysql_real_escape_string($empusers['name']),
 'helper_product' => array()
        );
    }